# Ajax get the error or success message from PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm post data to a php function using JSON post. I want to receive two different type of responses, **success** and **error**.
For example, the following function:

```
function some_function(){

    if ($error){
        echo "some error";
        exit;
    } else {    
        echo "everything is ok"
        exit;
    }

}
```

In this case, both messages will be returned as success. How can I make the error message return to the error function in the ajax?
Here's the ajax code:

```
jQuery.ajax({

    url: '<?php echo $url; ?>',
    data: response,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    type: 'POST',
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }

});
```

Comment: The error callback will be executed when the response from the server is not going to be what you were expecting. In your case, you are expecting Json. However, if the response is not in json format, it will go to error function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
jQuery.ajax({

    url: '<?php echo $url; ?>',
    data: response,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    type: 'POST',
    success:function(data){
        if(data['error']){
           alert(data['error']);
          }else{
             alert(data['success']);
          }
    },
    error: function(data, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }

});
```

On PHP page:

```
function some_function(){

        if ($error){
            $msg = array("error"=>"some error";
        } else {    
            $msg = array("success"=>"everything is ok");
        }
       echo json_encode($msg);die;
    }
```

Comment: I get `Undefined` in the console log :(

Answer (score 3):

If you want to force it to go to the error callback, then just force a wrong response from the server. Consider this example:

```
<?php

$url = 'index.php'; // sample value

function response($value) {
    if($value == 'true') {
        http_response_code(200);
        $data = array('status' => 200, 'message' => 'Server response is okay!');
        echo json_encode($data);
    } else {
        http_response_code(404);
    }
    exit;
}

if(isset($_POST['response'])) {
    $response = $_POST['response'];
    response($response);
}

?>


<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery.ajax({

        url: '<?php echo $url; ?>',
        data: {response: true}, // <-- set to TRUE or FALSE 
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data, errorThrown){
            console.log('error => ' + errorThrown);
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.The below JSON example is working fine.pls find it.

```
jQuery.ajax({

url: '<?php echo $url; ?>',
data: response,
dataType: 'JSON',
type: 'POST',
success: response_function
});

response_function(response){
 if(response.status == 1){
     //success response
     alert(response.message);
 }else{
      //failure response 
      alert(response.message);
      return false;
 }
 }
```

On the php script page

```
 function some_function(){

    if ($error){
        $msg = array("status"=> '1',    "message"=>"success message");
    } else {    
        array("status"=> '0', "message"=>"some error");
    }
   echo json_encode($msg);die;
}
```

Elangovan

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but as of JQuery 1.5 you'll need to use

```
error: function(data) {
    console.log(data['responseText']);
}
```

to get the json_encoded array your PHP is returning.